# For loop for a set of variables

Tags: shell, control-flow

I would like to run a for loop for a set of variables which I incorrectly denote as `{A,B}`. Following that my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
for {A,B} in {1,2}  {3,4} {5,6} {7,8}
do
echo A=$A B=$B
C=$(($A+$B))
echo Sum,C = $C
done
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to find sum of two numbers that I get in pairs. For my example, I want to print the numbers from each pair `A` and `B` and the sum `C=A+B`. Have modified the code a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I would use

```
while read A B
do echo A=$A B=$B
    C=$(( $A + $B ))
    echo Sum,C = $C
done<<EOF
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
EOF
```

For more complex operations dc is your friend (polish reverse notation!)

```
C=$(echo "$A $B +pq"|dc)
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
set   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
do    C="$(($1+$2))"
      shift 2
done
```

`for` doesn't allow for two simultaneous assignments in that way. So get an array and `shift` it away at your desired interval. If you use the standard shell `$@` array as I do above, then you'll always be working with your first two positionals `$1` and `$2`. If you use some kind of extension array then you'll be working with either `${array[0]}` and `${array[1]}` or `${array[1]}` and `${array[2]}` depending on your shell.

Else, with a `for` loop you can encode some kind of delimiter into each argument:

```sh
for x in 1+2 3+4 5+6 7+8
do  C="$(($x))"
done
```

...which actually works perfectly here, but that is usually not as cleanly done.

Answer (score 0):

I could make a possible work-around (Thanks @mikeserv for providing me the idea of array):

```
array=('1 2' '3 4' '5 6' '7 8')

for x in "${array[@]}"
do

A=`echo $x | awk '{print $1}'`
B=`echo $x | awk '{print $2}'`
echo A=$A B=$B

C=$(($A+$B))
echo Sum,C = $C

done
```

Suggest if further simplification is possible.

Comment: Well, yeah: `a=(1+2 3+4 5+6 7+8); for x in "${a[@]}"; do echo "Sum,C = $((C=$x))"; done`. You almost *never* want to call out to some other process within a loop like that. And if it's not as simple as all that, you can still split out the array members with shell param expansions like `for x in "${a[@]}"; do C=$((${x% *}+${x#* }))"; done`. The `awk` stuff is *way* overkill.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks. Point is that I don't always want to do sum. The sum is for a required simple demo. I can treat `A` and `B` separately to get something else, say `C=A^2` and `D=1-B^3`. I was thinking of function statement where I can use `A` and `B` as argument `$1` and `$2`. But I didn't try yet. :(

Comment: That's what I meant by suggesting the parameter expansions - if you set a delimiter you can divide on it. Try `A=${x% *} B=${x#* }; echo "\$A=$A \$B=$B"` to see what you get.

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks. What do `x% *` and `x#* ` do? Suppose, my set has three variables, i.e. `{A,B,C}`. Then could I have done in a similar fashion?

Comment: Yes, and no. They trim from the tail or head of a variable based on a pattern. Read [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).